# Google check out notifications

Tags: google-checkout

HI,

I need to get back the serial number or any unique value therefore if any transaction process got over or cut between the user and google checkout  am using only the HTML and python for storing the data database .I read the api call but iam getting error iam using only digital goods please say me in detail i already read the google checkout notification but the steps are comples for me and i didnt understand, i not aware of xml or java script so please say me how to do it..

Thanks in advance,

Nimmy...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Google Checkout Digital Delivery:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Digital_Delivery.html

There is also a Python wrapper library for Google Checkout:

http://code.google.com/p/gchecky/